# JSON (S3) to Redshift, can't load in YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ into timestamptz column

Tags: date, datetime, amazon-redshift

I am having issues loading a json file (date fields) in my S3 bucket into Redshift via the copy command.  The three columns that are problematic look like this...

```json
{
  ...
  "date":20201209,
  "dateChecked": "2020-12-09T24:00:00Z",
  "lastModified": "2020-12-09T24:00:00Z",
  ...
}
```

The DDL looks like...

```sql
create table table1 (
    ...,
    date date,
    dateChecked timestamptz,
    lastModified timestamptz,
    ...
);
```

and the copy command is ...

```
COPY {schema}.{table}
FROM 's3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_prefix}'
with credentials
'aws_access_key_id={access_key};aws_secret_access_key={secret_key}'
DATEFORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'
TIMEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MM:SSZ'
JSON 'auto ignorecase';
```

The way I understood it was that the `DATEFORMAT` would parse the `date` column and the `TIMEFORMAT` would handle the `timestamptz` columns. I am only getting an error on the `timestamptz` columns, specifically "Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ]".

Now I have also tried defining the `dateChecked` and `lastModified` columns as dates and using the DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' in the copy statement without the `TIMEFORMAT`. This works for those two columns but then the "date" column is null.

I've also tried every combination of `ACCEPTANYDATE`, `DATEFORMAT 'auto'`, `TIMEFORMAT 'auto'` commands, which returns null for all three columns.

My question is how do I load data with different date/time formats?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.